# org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection

Tags: java, spring

Решил изучить один проект. Там вот такое обращение к БД(**MySQL**) и конфиг. В логике используются 2 метода:

1. findByUsername из нашего интерфейса
2. save из JpaRepository

И при вызове любого выбрасывается ошибка 500 и вот такой стэк

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection

org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection

Собственно вопрос: в чём проблема и как исправить?

P.S. Поменял в DAO JpaRepository на CrudRepository. Заменил getOne на findOne(это же одно и то же?). Ошибка осталась

`UserDAO`

```
public interface UserDAO extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
User findByUsername(String username);
}
```

`appconfig-data.xml`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="net.proselyte.springsecurityapp.model"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven/>

    <jpa:repositories base-package="net.proselyte.springsecurityapp.dao"/>
</beans>
```

`User`

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Transient
    private String confirmPassword;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "user_roles", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Set<Role> roles;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getConfirmPassword() {
        return confirmPassword;
    }

    public void setConfirmPassword(String confirmPassword) {
        this.confirmPassword = confirmPassword;
    }

    public Set<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }
}
```

`UserServiceImpl` - класс-наследник интерфейса UserService с 2мя методами save и findByUsername

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;

    @Autowired
    private RoleDao roleDao;

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Override
    public void save(User user) {
        user.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
        roles.add(roleDao.findOne(1L));
        user.setRoles(roles);
        userDao.save(user);
    }

    @Override
    public User findByUsername(String username) {
        return userDao.findByUsername(username);
    }
}
```

Comment: Скорее всего это невозможность подключиться к БД, вы это обеспечили?

Comment: Вроде всё правильно настроил

Comment: По логу - нет соединения, это происходит когда ДБ вообще не доступна, либо порт не тот, или IP или еще что то

Comment: Господи... xml'ом еще пользуются? Лучше все это переписать в Application.properties

Comment: `PersistenceException` - часто это проблема с сущностями (Entities). Вставьте в ваш вопрос сущность `User`

Comment: Вы используете MySQL или PostgreSQL?

Comment: Сейчас всё закину, использовал PostrgeSQL, но теперь перешёл на MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ответ будет доработан, после уточнения вопроса!**

Пример `User.java`:

```
import lombok.*;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;
import java.util.Set;

@Data
@Entity
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "password")
    @NotEmpty(message = "*Please provide your password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "active")
    private boolean active;

    @Transient
    @NotEmpty(message = "*Please provide your password")
    private String matchingPassword;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_roles", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Set<Role> roles;
}
```

**Role.java**:

```java
import lombok.*;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@ToString
@Table(name = "role")
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "role_id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "role")
    private String role;
}
```

Рекомендую переписать Ваш .xml-файл в удобный `application.properties`.

**application.properties**:

```
server.port=80

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/spring_db?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password

# ==============================================================
# = Keep the connection alive if idle for a long time (needed in production)
# ==============================================================
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1

# ==============================================================
# = Show or not log for each sql query
# ==============================================================
spring.jpa.show-sql = true

# ==============================================================
# = Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, update)
# ==============================================================
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update

# ==============================================================
# = The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
# ==============================================================
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

# ==============================================================
# = Initialize the database using data.sql script
# ==============================================================
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
```

Изменить `JpaRepository` на `CrudRepository`:

```java
@Repository
public interface UserDAO extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {
User findByUsername(String username);
}
```

Comment: Рекомендацию обязательно выполню позже, как заработает xml, спасибо.
А cмена JpaRepository на CrudRepository не помогла

Comment: @Surv Для быстрого создания Entities используйте [lombok](https://projectlombok.org/).

Comment: @Surv зачем XML, если есть properties?) (ссылка на объяснения почему лучше [.properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380156/java-properties-properties-files-vs-xml)

Comment: Океюшки, а как подключить эти проперти? Или спринг их сам найдёт?

Comment: Спринг сам найдет @Surv

Comment: @Surv я могу быстро Вам накатать проект из данных, приведенных выше и скинуть через Git. Дальше Вам останется только поиграть с ним

Comment: Хм, штука в том, что у меня 3-4 xml и в одной они все импортятся в одну, я не знаю, как остальные переписать и ничего не сломать

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94949/discussion-between-antonio112009-and-surv).